# Add Anti-blur filter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove blurriness from the image or clicked picture. Or we can say **Anti-Blur** filter. However, I have searched a lot but did not found anything related to this filter. All I found is to add blurriness effect or filter, but as per requirement we require **Anti-Blur** filter.

Anybody know how to do this then Please let me know. It would be really appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the blurred image come from your application as well?  I mean, does your app do the blurring of the image?  Because if not then I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Not from my application, but yes we can have blur image from gallery. Our motive is to remove the blurriness from image (It can be from phone gallery or camera)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745200/remove-blur-effect-on-image-when-user-touch-the-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745200/remove-blur-effect-on-image-when-user-touch-the-screen) Refer this post. It may help!

Comment: @KetanParmar We already tried your given Link. It is not same as per what we need

Comment: @KetanParmar That won't do because in that thread, it requires that the image is in non-blurred condition.  There many ways to blur an image so it's practically impossible to find out how it was blurred unless you're the one who did the blurring like in that thread.

Comment: Ohh!! I see!! If you are adding already blurred image then i think it is not possible!!

Comment: At best you can check the formulas in this site http://yuzhikov.com/articles/BlurredImagesRestoration1.htm but as they said it only works in "typical" blurring.